# What does "Make the colours in the sky" mean in this context?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

> Ay, ay, ay
>
> I'm your little butterfly
>
> Green, black and blue
>
> Make the colours in the sky

Source: https://genius.com/Smiledk-butterfly-lyrics

Or as song:

Does it mean that green, black and blue make up the colours of the sky? Or do they mean that the butterfly is green, black and blue? If the latter, why not "Like the" instead of "Make the"?